# Android change value of variable on click

Tags: android, variables, onclicklistener

this is my code

```
final boolean identifier = true;
        if (i2 > i){
            if (identifier){
                v5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        identifier = false;
                    }
                });
            }
            if (!identifier){
                v5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        identifier = true;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

but this doesnt seem to be working out fine.
what i want is when v5 is clicked it will run a code that will change v5 onClicklistener

Comment: `Android change value of variable on click` : why `identifier` is `final` ?

Comment: why 2 onclicklistner?

Comment: im trying to make my view act as a switch on off. on the first click it will show contents and then on second click it will hide contents. the cycle continues like odd even

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K it needs to be final because it was access inside onClickListener

Comment: final boolean identifier = true; would not allow to change value remove final

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
  boolean identifier = false;

  v5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!identifier){
                     // first click
                     identifier=true;
                    }else{
                    // secondclick
                     identifier=false;
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: still the same. cant call identifier inside onClick if its not final and final variable doesnt seem to allow change of variable

Comment: make the identifier public and then try

Comment: @GilbertMendoza define you identifier outside the method(from onCreate).

Comment: sorry this code is within a void. i didnt post full code but i will try and if it works ill mark ur answer as correct

Comment: @GilbertMendoza  then define outside the void.

Comment: @Spartan sorry still doesn't work. on first click it shows contents but on second click it does nothing

Comment: really need to learn a lot of things. its not working on 2 if statement but it works on if else statement. thank you

Comment: @GilbertMendoza If you put 2 if statements then it will work one by one. If else is not like that. It works based on true or false (0 or -1), anyone of the statement will work.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove `final` from your `identifier` declaration, and make it a `class private field` so you can access it from your `OnClickListener`.
2. Set only one `OnClickListener` and have it check the value of `identifier`, like so:

   ```
   v5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           identifier = !identifier; // switch the value to false/true
           // update your UI
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
int identifier = 0;
        if (i2 > i){ 
            if (identifier=0){
                v5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override 
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        identifier = 1;
                    } 
                }); 
            } 
            if (identifier!=0){
                v5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override 
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        identifier = 0;
                    } 
                }); 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: identifier needs to be final and final variable cannot change its value

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `identifier` boolean before the `onCreate()` method. Also don't make it `final`. A value of any Final variable cannot be modified.

```
boolean identifier = true;
...

onCreate() {
...
onClick() {
identifier = false;
//your code
...
 }
}
```